# Particle System in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am making particle System in THREE.js by using SPARK.js, but the problem is that I am done with the code that is needed for the particle System but I am unable to see any thing on the screen related to the Particle System.

I am making a flame in THREE.js but I don't know why flame is not showing in the world.

Comment: If you dont create a jsfiddle or you dont show any code how can we help you?

Comment: Please have a look at this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558517/flame-is-not-showing-in-three-js-world

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at [Three.quarks](https://3quarks.org/)!. It's one of the best particle system engine for three.js. It supports texture batching, physics engine integration and everything else.